# Juniper Netscreen Remote - What is the interface / route config?

Tags: vpn, routing, netscreen

I'm wondering whether someone can tell me the mechanism by which traffic is routed to my office network via a VPN connection?
Once I understand that I will hopefully be able to sort out the issues I have.

I have a works laptop connected to my home network.
Configured to use dhcp, it gets a local IP assigned to it (192.168.0.x)
We use Netscreen Remote to create the tunnel to the office LAN (192.168.1.0)
Everything basically works fine, I just don't understand how.

ipconfig /all shows me just the one interface - My nic connected to the local lan.
route print   shows me the following:

> Active Routes:    
>         Network Destination
>         Netmask
>         Gateway
>         Interface
>         Metric        
>         0.0.0.0
>         0.0.0.0
>         192.168.0.1
>         192.168.0.9
>         20        
>         127.0.0.1
>         255.0.0.0
>         127.0.0.1
>         127.0.0.1
>         1        
>         192.168.0.0
>         255.255.255.0
>         192.168.0.9
>         192.168.0.9
>         20        
>         192.168.0.9
>         255.255.255.255
>         127.0.0.1
>         127.0.0.1
>         20        
>         192.168.0.255
>         255.255.255.255
>         192.168.0.9
>         192.168.0.9
>         20        
>         224.0.0.0
>         240.0.0.0
>         192.168.0.9
>         192.168.0.9
>         20        
>         255.255.255.255
>         255.255.255.255
>         192.168.0.9
>         192.168.0.9
>         1
>
> Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1 Persistent Routes: None

I can ping 192.168.1.x and get a reply immediately.
If I tracert to the same address I get 10 timeouts then a reply from the target address.

I just don't understand where the routing is being done...

Can anyone help please?

(P.S. Sorry about the layout - it says HTML table tags are supported but it doesn't look like they are)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be using Policy-Based VPN instead of Route-Based.  This means that traffic is based on the policies in the Netscreen instead of directing traffic to the tunnel interface, showing in the route print.

More information on the two types can be found on Juniper's site: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB4124